# Multiple highlight with autocmd in vimrc

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to use two autocmd, to highlight lines too long, and to highlight spaces at the end of lines, but I don't succeed, only the last of the two commands is displayed...
Is it possible ?

Here is the lines concerned:

```
augroup vimrc_autocmds
    autocmd BufEnter * highlight OverLength ctermbg=darkgrey guibg=#592929
    autocmd BufEnter * match OverLength /\%81v.*/
    autocmd BufEnter * highlight UnwantedSpaces ctermbg=red guibg=#red
    autocmd BufEnter * match UnwantedSpaces /\s\+$/
augroup END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use one `match` at a time.  If you want to use multiple you can use `2match` and `3match`.  You only have three of these to use simultaneously without defining syntax highlighting for what you're trying to match.